# How to program the outlook DLs using vbscript or some other language?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vbscript, distribution-list

Is it possible to add / remove a user from a outlook Distribution List using a program? I am not referring to the DLs in the local contacts list but the global address book. I have the permission to add / remove a user.

Also, is it possible to retrieve the users list with their properties based on the DL name?

Is it possible using vbscript or some other language?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and clarify what DL means?  I assume you mean Distribution List, but let's not assume.

Comment: I don't have the time to write a proper answer now, but I have done this before [with PowerShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378937(WS.10).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

This is very easy with the [Redemption library](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdo/RDODistListItem.htm).

```
set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
Session.Logon
set Contacts = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)
set DL = Contacts.Items.Add("IPM.DistList")
DL.DLName = "sample distribution list"
DL.AddMember("test <test@example.com>")
DL.Save
```